# Would requiring one function be faster than requiring full module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, function, module

I have a question.

Variant 1

```
const variableName = require("module-name");
variableName.functionName();
```

Variant 2

```
const { functionName } = require("module-name");
functionName();
```

Which variant is faster, if I need only one function from module?

Comment: Performance difference would be absolutely insignificant. Instead, worry about what's most clean and readable.

Comment: They do exactly the same amount of modue-loading.

Comment: Modules are loaded once, calling it again will just load a cached version of the module. Calling one function from the module will still load the entire module. What you are doing is object destructuring in variant 2 which loads the whole module then returns one function as a variable.